# Test if variable exists in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to do some computation in data.table that can columns names can vary.

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(x=1:10,y=1:10)
DT1[,list(y+x)]
```

Now if I do the same thing for DT that don't contain `y` column:

```
DT <- data.table(x=1:10)
DT[,list(y+x)]
```

I will get an error. Of course I can do the check outside the data.table:

```
if("y" %in% names(DT))DT[,list(y+x)]
```

I wonder if there a way to test this with the data.table itself , something like :

```
DT[exists("y"),y+x]
```

Comment: How about `DT[, if(exists("y"))y+x else x]`

Comment: @akrun thank you. why not! I will accept it if there i snot better solution. The problem with `ifelse` , that I have many variables to test and this will generate many nested `ifelse`.

Comment: If you don't want an error, what do you want?

Comment: @Frank Good question. Maybe not doing anything since there is no rows satisfying the criteria. But maybe I am asking a lot.

Comment: I guess you can use `try(DT[, list(y+x)], silent = TRUE)`. I don't do such serious programming and so have never needed it myself. It would probably just confuse me to have that error omitted.

Comment: @Frank catching error here is not a valid option. This is will create a confused situation. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use an `if/else` condition with `exists`

```
DT[, if(exists("y")) y+x else x]
```

If we have many variables to test, i.e. say 'y', 'z'

```
nm <- c('y', 'z')
DT[, if(Reduce(`&`, lapply(nm, exists))) y + z + x else x]
```

Comment: well. And what if we need to test it in the `ì` argument of `[`, something like `DT[existes(y) & !is.na(y),y+x]` (this don't work) ?

Comment: @agstudy As 'y' is not a column in 'DT', it will throw error though the 'i' argument works.

Comment: It might be more cautious to add a "inherits = FALSE" or specify "envir" in `exists` since with a global (but not in "DT") `y` variable, `exists("y")` will return `TRUE`